# How do I reset a user's name using Drush in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, drush, database

To change a password I would use:

```
drush user-password USERNAME --password="SOMEPASSWORD"
```

Is there a similar way to change a user's name using Drush from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built in Drush command, but you can use Drush's `sql-query` command (or `sqlq` shorthand) to update the user's name:

```
drush sql-query "update users set name='SOMENEWNAME' where uid=####"
```

Where `####` is the user's `uid` and `users` is the user table.

Comment: @arpitr, that is the wrong command, this is a question regarding changing a username, not a password.

Answer (score 5):

Just an update for those looking for this for Drupal 8.6+. The query should be

```
drush sql-query "UPDATE users_field_data SET name='somenewname' WHERE uid=##";
```